# React Native How to get the image name when using image picker?

Tags: javascript, react-native, file-upload, expo

I'm trying to use expo image picker to send image file to an API in form data but when I tried to use console.log to see the result, it does not show the image name. It shows the uri, type, width and height. How do I get the image name?

```
const pickImage = async () => {
        let result = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
          mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.Images, 
          aspect: [4, 3],
          quality: 1,
          base64: false,
        });
    
        console.log(result);
    
        if (!result.cancelled) {
          setImage(result.uri);
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Parse filename from uri

```js
if (!result.cancelled) {
  setImage(result.uri);

  const fileName = result.uri.split('/').pop();
  const fileType = fileName.split('.').pop();

  console.log(fileName, fileType);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [expo-document-picker](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/document-picker/) with `{type:'image/*'}` as  [DocumentPickerOptions](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/document-picker/#documentpickeroptions) which gives picked images details including name, type, uri etc... which is better alternate for expo-image-picker

Comment: expo-document-picker directs the user to the file manager. I need it to direct to image gallery

Answer (score 0):

From what I read in the [Image Picker docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-image-picker), the uri will be stored under the assets object:

```js
const pickImage = async () => {
  let result = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
    mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.Images, 
    aspect: [4, 3],
    quality: 1,
    base64: false,
  });
  // look at the keys, assets should be one
  console.log(Object.keys(result)); 
  if (!result.cancelled) {
    // It appears that assets is an array?
    setImage(result.assets[0].uri);
  }
};
```

Comment: I need the name of the image file, not the uri.